# JBox2d triangle not bouncing

Tags: polygon, physics, jbox2d

I am new to JBox2D and I am still trying to figure out how to use it. I am simply making use of the library by making various shapes and all that.
I find that when I make this object, which is supposed to be a triangle, it bounces correctly for the most part until it lands on one of the vertices, and just stops completely. It is the same vertex every time and I do not know why.

```
//right triangle constructor
public PhysObject(World wld, float posx, float posy, Color c, BodyType bdtp, float size) {
    color = c;

    x = posx;
    y = posy;
    s = size/2;

    bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.position.set(new Vec2(x, y));
    bd.bullet = true;
    bd.type = bdtp;


    body = wld.createBody(bd);



    ps = new PolygonShape();


    ps.m_vertexCount = 3;
    ps.m_vertices[0].set(-s, -s);
    ps.m_vertices[1].set(s, -s);
    ps.m_vertices[2].set(s, s);




    fd = new FixtureDef();
    fd.shape = ps;
    fd.friction = 0.3f;
    fd.restitution = 0.8f;
    fd.density = 1;

    body.createFixture(fd);

}
```

also here is the code for wen i draw it

```
private void drawTriangle() { 
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); 

        for(int i = 0; i < ps.m_vertexCount; i++) {
            glVertex2f(ps.m_vertices[i].x*30, ps.m_vertices[i].y*30);
        }

glEnd(); 
}
```

Comment: Did you check for size = 0 ?

Comment: good point, no ill fix that. but for testing purposes i have been only using 1f. I can draw it correctly too. Also, I am not sure if it collides correctly with other things such as a circle or square.

Comment: What argument types does the set method accept?  Any chance that 0.5 is being rounded down?  What happens when you set size=2?

Comment: all of the number variables or arguments are floats

Comment: Do you still have the problem when size is set to 2f?

Comment: yes, it always stops when it lands on the same vertex. Even when I set it to a different velocity or angular velocity.